# Searching mailcontact in Exchange via script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am having trouble searching for mailcontacts via a PowerShell-script, but if I run the same command manually in PowerShell, it works.

The command that works manually in PowerShell is:

```
Get-MailContact -Filter {name -like "*test*"}
```

But if I put the text in an variable like:

```
Get-MailContact -Filter {name -like "*$s*"}
```

I get another result; mainly nothing at all, where none of the contacts contain "test". Same if the command is in a script.

I can do the following, but search is the much slower, which I try to avoid

```
Get-MailContact -ResultSize unlimited | ? {$_.name -like "*$s*"}
```

P.S.
The script is loaded into a module, and the searchword is entered as a parameter. So the second command is prefered.

Comment: Does `Get-MailContact -Filter {name -like "*$($s)*"}` work for you?

Comment: No, nothing comes out from that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to this.

I found an explanation [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1200787-variables-give-unexpected-results-in-exchange-script?page=1#entry-5059348)
The short answer: the Exchange cmdlets are a little different syntactically.

After changing the curlybrackets to doublequotes, I got what I wanted.
The solution is as follows:

```
Get-MailContact -Filter "Name -like '$s'"
```

Also works for Get-DistributionGroup:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "Name -like '$s'"
```

Where `$s` contains the searchword surrounded with wildcards:

```
$searchword = "test"
$s = "*$searchword*"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filter sends through the string 'as-is', with no substitution (i.e. it is literally checking for a user called `*$s*`).  One way around this is to generate the pattern beforehand.  A bit clunky, but should work:

```
$name = "Mary"
$pattern = "*$name*"

Get-MailContact -Filter {name -like $pattern}
```

Comment: That did not work. It appears to fetch ALL mailcontacts 15.000+

Comment: Hmmmm ... I wasn't able to test with `Get-MailContact`, but did try with `Get-ADUser`, which uses an identical filter format and it worked as I suggested.  Maybe the cmdlet has some quirks with the filter - anything useful in the documentation?

Comment: Could be that `Get-MailContact` and `Get-ADUser` handles the filters differently. Unfortunately I didn't find anything in the docs.